# multi price in drupal commerce in drupal 7

Tags: 7, commerce

I have a shop created with drupal commerece modules,I enabled 2 currency in my shop , but only show one of them, I want to show price in 2 currency

something like this
**price :  10$  / 20 IRR**
I use **multi currency module** to achieve this job, but  I my problem is in payment  phase,
I use multi currency module to achieve this job,in multicurrency  module's setting I don't want  use  synchronize method, if you want have two field in my product , one form $ and another for IRR, I did this job by this method

first enable IRR currency in
 **admin/commerce/config/currency**
 then in
 **admin/commerce/config/currency/handling**
under *Enable dedicated price fields for Product* check **Iranian Rial**
 by doing this  another field added you my product ( ** Price for IRR** ), this is good , after this I enable  **currency selector ** block ,in checking out process by switching the currency I don't see any change in current currency of billing and cart. :(
why changing currency not changing cart currency?

Comment: Did you try to workaround rules for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Commerce Multicurrency](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_multicurrency) module enhances some of the multi-currency capabilities of Drupal Commerce. You can show ***two or more currency*** for a product and check this video [tutorial](http://commerceguys.com/blog/commerce-module-tuesday-commerce-multicurrency) and [this one](http://www.drupalcommercecamp.ch/de/sessions/multi-currency-shops-drupal-commerce)

> Current features:
>
> - UI for fine granular definition of exchange rates.
> - (Every currency combination can be defined separately if needed)
> - Synchronization of currency exchange rates directly from the European Central Bank (ECB).
> - UI to specify which rates shall be synchronized and which are handled manually.
>     Generation of currency specific price fields inclusive generation of rule-set to handle them.
> - hooks for easy integration of custom currency exchange rate sources.

[image]

this tutorial will help you without sync http://mcaleaa.wordpress.com/2012/04/08/drupal-commerce-multicurrency-recipe/

Comment: tnx, I konw this, but  select currency  block not work for my in cart ,when I use syn current work good, but when I dont use sync mod and use  dedicate field  not work

Comment: do you know this https://drupal.org/project/currency_commerce

Comment: I want have 2 field for price, one for dollar and another for IRR , no using any caculation of equal currency, two field with two  value, and in changing currency  in cart currency of cart which field it read from it change

Comment: yes, in question i mentioned that I used this module, my problem is with this module

Comment: this tutorial will help you without sync http://mcaleaa.wordpress.com/2012/04/08/drupal-commerce-multicurrency-recipe/

Comment: This link removed ??  404 :(